# Stuck at exporting DDL with mariadb-dump to drop database and recreate it

Tags: mariadb

Consider this image. This is an export made from a MariaDB database to only include its schema, and drop the database first and recreate it:

[image]

As you can see:

1. I want to **drop && create** the database
2. There are no routines, and no events
3. I want to **create** tables
4. We do have lots of **auto increments** but I don't know the value of that box
5. There are no triggers
6. And I want no data

This is what I wrote, but it does not create the `drop database` statement:

```
mariadb-dump -u root -pPassword -d --add-drop-database Accounts
```

What statement would match this Adminer export?